# Code to real_escape all parameters clears all parameters

Tags: php

I've used this PHP code to escape all the parameters which I pass:

```
<?php

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_array($value)){
        $_GET[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
}

$offset = (isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : null);

echo "Offset is " . $offset;

?>
```

In this example no matter what I pass as "offset" it returns "Offset is ". If I remove the foreach loop it returbs "Offset is Hello" (or whatever I pass).

Why is the fornext loop losing the parameters - I've been using the code for months and it has always worked before!

Comment: If you activated error reporting or checked your error logs I'm sure you'd see a bunch of messages telling you that mysql couldn't establish a database connection...

Comment: @deceze exactly what I thinking and testing; @andy: try `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` adding those two line to the begining of the script and see what they tell you.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working:

```
<?php
$_GET['offset'] = 'Hello';
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_array($value)){
        $_GET[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
}

$offset = (isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : null);

echo "Offset is " . $offset;

?>
```

Result:

```
Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in ... on line 5
Offset is Hello
```

As you see value is correct, so probably in your case `$_GET['offset']` contains something else and you use `mysql_` deprecated functions by the way.

Comment: I would suggest using PDO as a replacement. +1 for the mention of deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, stupid me, I didn't make the connection in my mind between MySQL and parsing the parameters. All the other code where it works I make a connection to a MySQL database first.

Thanks.